# How can I display the second submenu?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-5

I want to create a menu with a submenu in Laravel. I wrote this code but it doesn't display the second sub-menu.

For example, I want to show the submenu of `Another dropdown`. But it did not display.

Look at this picture for example. i.stack.imgur.com/d8dfk.png

**My version of Bootstrap is 5.3.**

[image: dropdown]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="fa">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-T5m5WERuXcjgzF8DAb7tRkByEZQGcpraRTinjpywg37AO96WoYN9+hrhDVoM6CaT" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">خدمات</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
              <li class="dropend">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">سفارش طراحی سایت</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                  <li class="dropend">
                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#">سازمانی</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu shadow">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">اداری</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">شرکتی</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">اصناف</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">بیمه</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropend">
                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#">گردشگری</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu shadow">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">هتل</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">رستوران</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">گردشگری</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">طراحی سایت اختصاصی</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">سئو</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">تولیدمحتوا</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">گرافیک</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">پیامک</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">پشتیبانی</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">گوگل ادورز</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">اپلیکیشن</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I imported this code from here https://www.codehim.com/demo/bootstrap-5-mega-menu-responsive-examples/

Category.php

```
public function children ()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

Could you please help me with how to achieve it? I've tried to use several bootstrap classes, or even hardcode float left and right. Nothing helped. My code is above:

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @Coola  My version of Bootstrap is 5.3

Comment: Can you share the generated HTML?

Comment: Please share the exact HTML which is being generated in your app. Seeing a tutorial is not helpful as there may be something wrong in your specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in the lines

```php
 <a href="{{ $children->path() }}" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">{{ $children->title }}</a>
```

and

```
                      <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="{{ $child->path() }}">{{ $child->title }}</a>
```

The href should be `href="#"` so that it does not act like a link, and act like a button for the dropdown.

try changing to:

```php
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">{{ $children->title }}</a>
```

and

```php
                      <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#">{{ $child->title }}</a>
```

If it doesn't work I have asked for more information in the comments above.

### Update

You need to add `data-bs-auto-close="outside"` to all your `dropdown-toggle` elements.

So for example

```php
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside">{{ $children->title }}</a>
```

See [JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coolakul/f283Lcun/5/)

Comment: I replaced your code, but my problem did not solve yet.

Comment: Look at this picture for example. https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8dfk.png

Comment: Can you answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75951536/how-does-design-like-this-with-bootstrap-5-3